# Why I am not seeing recent events under RDS default sqlserver_audit parameter group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have RDS SQL server instance and it has the default `sqlserver_audit` parameter group, but I am not seeing any recent events. What is the issue?

A screen shot of what I am seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Events generated from `sqlserver_audit` *parameter group* (HIPAA audit) are not directly visible to you in AWS Console. For more info about HIPAA audit implementation in RDS for SQL Server see [this AWS forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=846178).

When you want to see events from your SQL Server audits, you need to use `SQLSERVER_AUDIT` *option*. In that case, RDS will stream data from audits on your RDS instance to your S3 bucket. You can also configure retention time, during which those .sqlaudit files are kept on RDS instance and you can access them by `msdb.dbo.rds_fn_get_audit_file`. For more info see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.Audit.html).

In both cases, "Recent events" will contain only important messages related to your instance, not audited events. So for example, whenever RDS can't access your S3 bucket for writing in order to store your audits, it will tell you so in "Recent events".

Answer (score 1):

Vasek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65636248/4139786) helped me understand why I wasn't seeing logs show up in my s3 bucket and it was because the inline IAM policy attached to my IAM role used to transfer the audit logs was incorrect.

If you use the automated options-group creation wizard to add the `SQLSERVER_AUDIT` option to your RDS instance, be sure you don't include a trailing slash on your s3 key prefix.

**The incorrect IAM policy statement the AWS option group creation wizard created is shown below.**

```
{    
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:PutObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-audit-logs-bucket/audits//*"  # <---- INCORRECT
    ]
}
```

I changed my `SQLSERVER_AUDIT`  options group to use the bucket's root and changed the IAM policy to the following correct configuration shown below and my audit logs started showing up in my S3 buck

```
{    
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:PutObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-audit-logs-bucket/*"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.Audit.html):

> RDS uploads the completed audit logs to your **S3 bucket**, using the **IAM role** that you provide. If you enable retention, RDS keeps your audit logs on your DB instance for the configured period of time.

So the log evens will be in S3, assuming all permissions are set correctly, not in the RDS Events console.